# initWithCoder leak

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks

I have a leak in my initWithCoder. 
Can anyone help me see what's wrong?

In my custom classes I have tried both using self. and without...

```
-(id) initWithCoder: (NSCoder *) decoder {  
    if( self = [super init] )
    {
        persons = [[decoder decodeObject] retain];
        title = [[decoder decodeObject] retain];
    }
    return self;
 }

-(id) initWithCoder: (NSCoder *) decoder {
    if( self = [super init] )
    {
       self.name = [decoder decodeObject];
       self.address = [decoder decodeObject];
       self.email = [decoder decodeObject];
       self.comment = [decoder decodeObject];
    }   
    return self;
}


NSData *getData = [[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path] autorelease];

Group = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:getData] retain];


......
......
......



[Group release];
```

Comment: What told oyu there was a leak? This specific code looks ok.

Comment: It is? Leaks tool report 986 NSCFStrings which is the number of objects NSData holds. Responsible Frame: [Group initWithCoder:] when I open the stack trace it shows the line self.name = [decoder decodeObject]

Comment: I don't know if this has anything to do with it, but you're using an NSKeyedUnarchiver...shouldn't you be using `decodeObjectForKey:`?

Comment: Are they being released in `-dealloc`?

Comment: Remove the retain, and post results.

Comment: removing retain crashes the app

Comment: yep, they are released

Comment: If you click the arrow next to the memory address, it will show you the retain/release/autorelease history for that address. *Much* more useful than just the thing that first allocated it, in my experience...